# VirtualBox Sdk Java - Executing a command inside guest OS from host OS

Tags: java, virtualbox

I'm trying to create a user inside guest OS(Ubuntu server) from host OS(Ubuntu 14.04).

Here's my code

```
IGuestProcess process = null;

ISession session = manager.getSessionObject(); //VirtualBoxManager

machine.lockMachine(session, LockType.Shared); //IMachine

IConsole console = session.getConsole();

IGuest guest = console.getGuest();

IGuestSession guestSession = guest.createSession("registerdUserWithRights", "hisPasswd", "", "");

Long time = 100000L;

GuestSessionWaitResult result = guestSession.waitFor(time, time);       

if(result == GuestSessionWaitResult.Start)
    process = guestSession.processCreate("adduser --disabled-password --gecos \"\" username", null, null, null, 0L);

ProcessWaitResult waitResult = process.waitFor(1L, time);

if(waitResult == ProcessWaitResult.Start)
    System.out.println("started");
```

However this fails at `ProcessWaitResult waitResult = process.waitFor(1L, time);`. I keep getting

> > VBox error: VirtualBox error: rc=0x80bb0005 The specified file was not found on guest (0x80bb0005)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. The trick was to issue the entire path of the command. I got that using `which <command>` . Also I had to pass the arguments for the command in a separate arraylist.

```
IGuestProcess process = null;

ISession session = manager.getSessionObject(); //VirtualBoxManager

machine.lockMachine(session, LockType.Shared); //IMachine

IConsole console = session.getConsole();

IGuest guest = console.getGuest();

IGuestSession guestSession = guest.createSession("registerdUserWithRights", "hisPasswd", "", "");

Long time = 100000L;

GuestSessionWaitResult result = guestSession.waitFor(time, time);       

List<String> argumentsForProcess = Arrays.asList("--disabled-password", "--gecos", "'" + name + "'", username);

if(result == GuestSessionWaitResult.Start)
    createUser = guestSession.processCreate("/usr/sbin/adduser", argumentsForProcess, null, null, 0L);


ProcessWaitResult waitResult = process.waitFor(1L, time);

if(waitResult == ProcessWaitResult.Start)
    System.out.println("started");
guestSession.close();
session.unlockMachine();
```

Answer (score 1):

I set the executable path as null and put the executable path in argurments[0]

```
  List<String> argumentsForProcess = Arrays.asList( "/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "/home/webserver/vm60-docker/webserver/service-1.0.0.jar");

  process = guestSession.processCreate(null, argumentsForProcess, null, null, 0L);
```